# Can't find winsock.c or winsock implementation

Tags: c, network-programming

I want to read the source code of winsock, but I only see header which is winsock.h. where is winsock.c located I need to read the source code implementation so bad.

Comment: Well, Microsoft is not quite known for disclosure of their sources... Good luck! -- **Why** do you want to read the source?

Comment: I found the vulnerability which might come from the library so I want to see if it is or not

Comment: Chances are that your application "opens the gate", not a library in billions of uses. Even if such errors are found sometimes.

Comment: What did you try already to find the source?

Comment: I searched on github google and look through the gcc files

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add this information about your research so far. -- If it's not disclosed by MS, I'm sure you can not find it, at least legally. -- GCC has nothing to do with this.

Comment: Yeah...you will need to contract with MS or trusted partner, and sign an NDA:(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As to my knowledge Microsoft never released source code for that library. The best you can do is use Ida pro or simillar software to decompile `Ws2_32.dll` or `Ws2_32.lib`. That is the closest you will get to the source code, but it will be in pseudo C.